When and why does GitHub delete old workflow runs?
A lot of people on Stack Overflow ask how to delete old GitHub workflow runs. I have the opposite problem: I want my workflow runs not to disappear.
E.g. my repo (and others) hasn't had any activity for some time, and the CI badge says "no status". Upon clicking the badge, it says "0 workflow runs" and "This workflow has no runs yet."
That is not true! There were workflow runs in the past! Why did they disappear? What can I do so that my old runs don't disappear?

As stated in the GitHub official documentation:

By default, GitHub stores build logs and artifacts for 90 days, and this retention period can be customized.

To customize this retention in a GitHub Organization:

By default, the artifacts and log files generated by workflows are retained for 90 days before they are automatically deleted. You can adjust the retention period, depending on the type of repository:

For public repositories: you can change this retention period to anywhere between 1 day or 90 days.
For private repositories: you can change this retention period to anywhere between 1 day or 400 days.


If you need to store those logs for audit or other scenarios (a longer retention time) I suggest to evaluate using a cloud storage tool (like AWS S3 bucket for example) to store them outside GitHub.

I just want a badge with the results of the most recent test run. As of 2024-05-22, this has the least recent still-available action result from 2023-03-24. Also that links to this help page, which says "GitHub.com retains checks data for 400 days. After 400 days, the data is archived. 10 days after archival, the data is permanently deleted.". I guess that's the actual answer to my question.

From what I understand, the most recent run might not be available for the badge to render it after a certain amount of time. How old are your runs here?

Two years or so? That's why they're not showing...

I don't know if the archival rule was always as it is today, but as your runs are two years old, they have already been archived and completely deleted. So unfortunately, you won't be able to retrieve them, no matter what :/
